# How do I get a public key out of .pfx private key

Tags: rsa, md5, sha1

How do I get a public key out of private key .pfx, my document is signed using rsa SHA1 algorithm I want to generate a public key for the use in another server, so my documents will be digitally signed using private key and opened by a public key in a remote server, I currently have a private key .pfx, how can I get a public key out of it?

Comment: or how do I get a public key in .pfx format.

Comment: I used this command to create .pfx file 
openssl pkcs12 -export -out billing.pfx -inkey billing.key -in billing.crt

Comment: Given the openssl command you used to create the pfx in the first place, the public key is contained within the certificate `billing.crt`.

Comment: Thanks bro... for the insight!

Comment: openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in billing.crt -inkey billing.key -out client.pfx   I have used this command to create a client certificate, I have a  normal certificate, private key and a public key which files do i need to give to the verifying server is it public.key or public.pfx, thanks in advance

Comment: Generally pfx/p12 is used to contain a public *and* private key together, so you don't want to distribute that. The certificate (crt/cer) would be the normal way to provide *just* the public key.

Comment: Now, I have understood thanks so much Iridium